# Как удалять элемент строки по его индексу?

Tags: java

Я знаю про `substring()`, но я бы хотел делать проверку по строке, типо нам дана строка: `(<({[{}]}>)`. И у меня есть алгоритм валидации этой строки, на эту строку нам выведется **false** и для этого **false** я хочу сделать проверку такую, что у нас будет удаляться элемент в строке  и если на вывод подастся **true** то мы выведем эту `i`. Не могли бы подсказать или дать по возможности полное решение для моей задумки?

```
    (<({[{}]}>) - <({[{}]}>) - false
    (<({[{}]}>) - (({[{}]}>) - false
    (<({[{}]}>) - (<{[{}]}>) - true, i=3
```

Comment: ты сам хоть понял что написал?

Comment: Ну... Да. Я просто хочу узнать как удалитьэлемент строки по его индексу, ибо метод replace заменит сразу все нужны скобки

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            sc.close();
            if(balancedParenthensies(str)==true){
                System.out.println("True");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("False");
                StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(str);
                for(int j=0;j<str.length();j++){
                build.deleteCharAt(j); 
                if (balancedParenthensies(build.toString())==true){
                    System.out.println(j+1);
                    System.out.println(build);
                    break;
                }
                else{ build = new StringBuilder(str);}
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вот что у меня получилось)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А что тут править можно? Вроде по правилам кинул код

Comment: Так это _решение_ вашей проблемы?  Или скорее всего неработающий код?  Скорей всего код нерабочий, так как он пытается удалять по одному символу поочередно, пока  строка не станет _валидной_.  то нужно отредактировать и вставить его в **вопрос**